# Unable to retrieve user information from django templates

Tags: python, django

i want to use loged in user information in my base template

```
{% if request.user.username %}
        <a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
        <a href="/accounts/login">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is not working? can you be more concrete on what is happening?

Comment: What do you have in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: Are you passing a `RequestContext` to your render call?

Comment: Make sure you have `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. It is the processor responsible for passing request.user before reaching the controller

Comment: request.user.username is not returning the loged username

Comment: what is it returning then ?

Comment: its returning nothing i think its not calling request object. Where i have to use django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth ... please do not mind if its silly question. i am new to django...

Comment: Please check the complete code at git_hub link https://github.com/avinashdevicode/example

Comment: Can you post the view method that you are using to render this template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.template import RequestContext
def top(request):
    return render_to_response('top.html',{}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Do i need to use the above code in view.py ? .. but how it will pass the information to my base template ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to check if they're logged in to display the login or logout links, I would use is_authenticated instead

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="/accounts/login">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

If you are wanting to use information from the user, you can use the variables in the user class {{ user.username }}

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi, {{ user.first_name }}, <a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="/accounts/login">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

I use code with this structure in my base.html and it works well. I don't have anything in the template_content_processor - it works in the template on its own.